# Как использовать значение DEFAULT в файле parameters.php?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Мне надо передать в компонент значение DEFAULT добавленного поля (на случай, если пользователь его не передал или передал пустое), но откуда его достать я так и не понял, в arParams его просто нет.

```
"INFO_TEXT"=>Array(
        "NAME"=>"Заголовок формы",
        "TYPE"=>"STRING",
        "DEFAULT"=>Home::get('CONSULTATION_FORM_INFO'),
    )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройке формы дефолтное значение появляется, но применяется лишь после сохранения, в чем тогда смысл этого параметра, если я могу задать это дефолтное значение сразу в компоненте при проверке на существование?

Comment: Чтобы пользователь видел. Иначе он в настройках будет видеть пустое значение, а по факту будет какое-то не пустое.

Comment: @ВикторКарев, Это чисто видимость? А не использование этого параметра по умолчанию?

Comment: Не использование. Если этот параметр не заполнен, то когда пользователь откроет редактирование параметров компонента, этот параметр будет заполнен значением по умолчанию. Когда пользователь сохранит параметры, это значение запишется. Мы как бы показываем пользователю, какое значение будет использоваться по умолчанию. И, соответственно, должны сами его использовать, если параметр не задан.

Comment: @ВикторКарев, Понял, спасибо!